# Simplify image management in articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, content

I recently tried to explain someone how to add images from a digital camara to an article in Joomla, and I noticed how cumbersome this actually is. Basically one has to do the following steps:

1. Find image in Windows Explorer and resize from a resolution of 6 (or more) megapixels using an image editor.
2. Press "Add image" button below editor in Joomla
3. Find upload section at the bottom, locate file on computer and remember to click "Upload"
4. Locate file in Joomla media manager and click "insert".
5. If you forgot to set image alignment, you have to edit the source code or insert image again.

How can I make this process easier? I know K2 will resize inserted images as needed, but I'd rather use the normal article manager.

Comment: There are plugins for resize images on server but you would probably hit file upload limits. IN JCE editor you can upload the images while in article if you want to do it from one page?

Comment: You are correct the process is very tedious especially for non-techy users! There are a few extensions you may want to have a look at such as http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/articles-images/16743 and http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/articles-images/25482 I'd also like to see an in-built feature for this situation though.

Comment: You can actually drag and drop directly into the JCE editor, just FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the [JCE Image Manager](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/component/zoo/item/image-manager-extended-4), an extension to the popular Joomla Content Editor. It requires a paid subscription, but it allows you to resize your images on upload, and even create thumbnails automatically. The thumbnails can then be used to create a modal popup to display the full size image.

[image: JCE Image upload dialog]

Additionally, it includes a basic image editor that allows you to crop, rotate and resize your images, as well as adding a couple of filters.

For a simpler solution, the plugins recommended by @johnny_s ([this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/articles-images/16743) and [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/articles-images/25482)) looks very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I started a similar discussion on LinkedIn a while ago (sorry, I can't find a link now). Apart from JCE Image Manager (already mentioned in another answer) JI Blog Tools and Forms2Content were also recommended as extensions that help simplify adding images.

JCE Image Manager: http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/downloads/plugins/image-manager-extended

JI Blog Tools: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/article-elements/articles-summary/22187

Forms2Content: http://www.form2content.com

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the standard joomla media manager and the way you add intro and full article image, you can use an administrator module, MK Dropzone, with a dropzone area to upload and resize images creating different size from your single image: small, medium and large.

This is a paid solution but works great

http://codecanyon.net/item/mk-dropzone-upload-and-resize-images-for-joomla/11668771

[image]